# My external HD is not showing up

Tags: 10.10, external-hdd

I have an external HD that I saved all my data on from my old windows setups. I now want to access that info on my ubuntu machine and the drive isn't mounting. I've floated around the help files and I am not finding anything that works.

the drive is firewire LaCie

My jolicloud machine sees it no problem. Ubuntu on the other hand does not.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` with your harddisk plugged in ?

Comment: Here you go - 
Disk /dev/sda: 40.0 GB, 40007761920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4864 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003a87d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        4659    37419008   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            4659        4864     1648641    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            4659        4864     1648640   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Please use http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and provide the link instead.

Comment: Forgive me for I am new to this, what will pastebin do for me? I clicked it and all I got was a download txt. What am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: After you put your text in pastebin, copy the link for that page. It should look something like this: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/589832/

Answer (score 1):

When you had the drive plugged into Windows, did you go to the bottom right hand of the screen and click Remove Hardware?  Drives will not mount unless you plug it back into a Windows PC and then do that step, then plug it back into your Ubuntu PC and it will be recognised and will be accessible for use.

Comment: i dont think that is true, is it?

Answer (score 0):

So after walking away from my laptop for a while, I came back and out of no where it recognized the HDD. Then it disappeared... Then it came back!

I don't get it, but it's here, and it works.

Thanks.

Perhaps it's the cable, the HDD, or the firewire port?